# idangero.us swiper control

Tags: jquery, swiper.js

I am using iDangero.us Swiper plugin and I need a solution for syncing multiple swiper instances.

Please check below the code

```
<div class="swiper-container swipe1">    
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">        
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>        
    </div>
</div>  

<div class="swiper-container swipe2">    
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">        
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>        
    </div>
</div>  

<div class="swiper-container swipe3">    
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">        
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>        
    </div>
</div>
```

If i swipe any one of the swiper, remaining 2 swiper instances also needs to be slide.

How we can achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add some of your attempt to reach your desired behavior.

Comment: Got it worked by using slideTo API function. Check the below code

<code>
var newSwiper = $('.swiper').swiper({     
 slidesPerView:'1',
 onSlideChangeStart: function(){
  otherSwiper-1.slideTo( newSwiper.activeIndex, 500, false )
  otherSwiper-2.slideTo( newSwiper.activeIndex, 500, false )            
 },
});    
</code>

Thank you all....

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with swiper control.

```
swiperOne.params.control = swiperTwo;
swiperTwo.params.control = swiperOne;
```

This way both Swipers are synched.